# typecheck a script without network connection?

Tags: tezos-client, type-checker

I'm trying to typecheck a script, but *sometimes* get the following error:

```
$ tezos-client typecheck script helloTezos.tz
Error:
  Unrecognized command.
  Try using the man command to get more information.
```

This appears to be the case whenever my local `tezos-node` process is still warming up or in some other strange state.

The error message is misleading! Why is a network connection needed at all for type checking?

I built tezos according to the following instructions: http://tezos.gitlab.io/mainnet/introduction/howtoget.html#build-from-sources

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Typechecking is done via a protocol RPC, if the node hasn't loaded the protocol, the RPC won't be available. You can also use a sandboxed node to typecheck contracts.

Why is the coupling with the node so tight? It shouldn't be, but there is one type of value that can be stored in a contract... Other contracts. The typechecker needs access to the ledger state to check the type of these contracts. Ultimately, this should be uncoupled but, today, it still is.

Comment: I too am running into this, using `alphanet.sh`. I can run ```./alphanet.sh client rpc get /stats/gc``` and get back stats, so I'm assuming the `rpc` endpoints are good to go, but all I ever get is the `Unrecognized command` for type checking. I started everything with just the `./alphanet.sh start`.  Also, should `typecheck` show up in ```./alphanet.sh client man```? _(I don't see it)_